# How to make a palette look exactly like a MacOS window?

Tags: gui-construction

Is there anyway to style a pallete so that it looks like a native window:

[image]

```
CreatePalette[
 Grid[{{Button["<"], Button[">"], 
    InputField["search"]}, {Style[TextCell["Your mac is up to date"], 
     White], Checkbox[]
    }}, Dividers -> {None, Center}], WindowTitle -> "Software Update",
  Background -> RGBColor[0.28, 0.24, 0.24]]
```

[image]

Comment: It does look like a native window, it just does not support dark mode.

Comment: but what about the search bar, buttons, text and alignments?

Comment: The title bar is the wrong color and size as well

Comment: Yes, it just doesn't support dark mode (like many other Mac apps).

Comment: No you cannot add items to the caption bar.  You can get the fonts and colors via CurrentValue (which are documented in v12.0).  Dark Mode is not currently supported.